# Sell Stop-Limit triggered on bid or ask?

Tags: options, stock-markets

If an option has a spread of BID $1 and ASK $1.50 and a sell stop-limit is placed with a STOP $1.20 and a LIMIT $1.15, is the stop triggered by the bid or the ask? That is, this order will not try to execute the limit until the price gets to or goes below $1.20, and if triggered off the bid, then that will execute immediately. I've been told conflicting information as I thought it was based off the ask and not the bid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy Limit and Buy Stop orders are triggered when the Ask  reaches your order's price.

Sell Limit and Sell Stop orders are triggered when the Bid  reaches your order's price.

Comment: Right, so a Sell Stop-Limit should have the Stop triggered on Ask